# Dart symbol literals

Tags: dart

I was reading [this](https://dart.dev/articles/archive/zones) document on Zones and it has the following code:

```
runZoned(() {
  print(Zone.current[#key]);
}, zoneValues: { #key: 499 });
```

I tried to find more docs symbol literals, but I couldn't, they are very scarce.

I typed this code for a test:

```
var a = #b;
```

And I can see that `a` is a `Symbol`.

How does a `Symbol` literal work?

What does it reference to?

Just by creating one I create a new unique `Symbol`?

Comment: Just as a note. Chapter 16.8 (page 88) in the Dart spec describe how they works and the reason behind them: https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Symbols are not unique. They are intended to represent source names at runtime, so the symbol value of the symbol literal `#a` (which can also be written [`const Symbol("a")`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Symbol/Symbol.html)) represents the identifier `a`.

Symbols occur only in the more dynamic parts of Dart. In particular they are used in the representation of *named arguments* used by the [`Invocation`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Invocation-class.html) class (the argument passed to `noSuchMethod`) and the [`Function.apply`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Function/apply.html) function. If your platform has access to [`dart:mirrors`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html), they are also used there, and that was the original use they were introduced for.

You shouldn't *need* to use symbols outside of those cases, but in some situations, like the `#key` above, it's just an *easy* way to provide a reproducible (not unique) token that carries its own name. Or, if you want a token that is unique to your own library, you can make a symbol for a *private* name, `#_foo`. This represents the library-private `_foo` identifier, which no other library can reproduce.

Having a representation of source names that is not a string allows, e.g., a Dart to JavaScript compiler to minify the names and not have to retain the longer source identifiers in the deployed code.