# Are Symbols deprecated in Dart?

Tags: dart

From reading this (https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-a-dart-symbol) it seems that Symbols are deprecated in Dart. But I've had trouble finding an explanation for why to avoid them. This answer ([Dart symbol literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185676/dart-symbol-literals)) gives some explanation of what symbols are in dart, certain cases when they're commonly used. And it suggests "you shouldn't need to use symbols outside of those cases." Shouldn't need is different than shouldn't. Are they deprecated or not? If they are deprecated, why?

The docs here: (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Symbol-class.html) don't mention deprecation. I couldn't find any mention of Symbols here: (https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart) either for or against.

In this example the symbol seems to be working as I'd like it to:

```dart
class TrafficLight {
  Symbol color;
  TrafficLight(this.color);
}

void main() {
 var t = TrafficLight(#red);
 print(t.color == #red);
 print(t.color == #green);
}


//returns:

// > true
// > false
```

If I have thousands of traffic lights, thousands of identical Strings are a waste of RAM. What's the common / best practice way of handling these type of situations in Dart? Enums? Creating a `TrafficLightColor` class?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this issue.

#### Response to comments

@julemand101

```dart
void main() {
  String a = '123';
  String b = a;
  a += 'foo';
  print('a: $a');
  print('b: $b');
}
```

return is:
`a: 123foo b: 123`
If they were pointing to the same object, I'd expect return to be
`a: 123foo b: 123foo`

@julemand101, You're absolutely right, my thinking was off. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Looks like a case for an enum. Also note that "thousands of identical Strings are a waste of RAM" is properly not true here since equal strings will in most cases point to the same object since strings are immutable.

Comment: @julemand101, responded with code sample in edit.

Comment: What do you mean? As I said, `String` is immutable so when you try make a change to a `String` using e.g. the `+` operator, you are creating a entire new `String` object while the others are kept (unless all references are lost, in which case the garbage collector will remove it). In you case, you have two reference variables, `a` and `b`. In the start the points to the same `String` instance in memory. But when you do `a = a + 'foo'` you are creating a new `String` and change `a` to point at this new `String`. See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/operator_plus.html

Comment: An example. Use the `identical` method to "Check whether two references are to the same object." in this code: `void main() {
  String a1 = 'a';
  String a2 = 'a';
  print(identical(a1, a2));
}` and you will see it returns `true`.

Comment: I am not saying this will always be the case since you can construct two `String` objects to have the same content but not be `identical`. What I am saying is that in most cases, it is not a problem in the scale of your statement "thousands of identical Strings are a waste of RAM". But still, use a `enum` :)

Comment: @julemand101 You're absolutely right, my thinking was off. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbols are not deprecated. They are *mainly* used for reflection-like functionality like `dart:mirrors`, [`Object.noSuchMethod`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Object/noSuchMethod.html) (the [`memberName`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Invocation/memberName.html) and [`namedArguments`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Invocation/namedArguments.html) names) and [`Function.apply`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Function/apply.html) (again the named arguments names). If you don't need those, you likely don't *need* to bother with symbols. You can, they're just objects, but not particularly useful objects.
(Some libraries use private symbols, like `#_foo` to create a library-private sentinel object, but you could also just do `final _mySentinel = Object();`.)

The best way to handle the traffic lights situation is enums.

You could use symbol literals (`#red`, `#green`) or string literals (`"red"`, `"green"`) or magic numbers (`1`, `2`), but the only approach to creating a fixed set of values to represent a specific thing that is language and type-system supported is enums.
You can make your own enum-like class if you want to, and it'll be just as good as enums, except that you won't get a warning if you forget a case in a switch.
(If you do use string literals, you'll likely find that they are canonicalized too, so the string data won't take up more space whether they occur once or thousands of times).